# Why does the sound keep going out of sync in VLC?

Tags: vlc-media-player

There seems to be a problem with VLC that started some months ago. When watching a movie, the sound slowly starts going out of sync. If I close VLC and open the movie again to the spot it was at before, the sound is no longer out of sync.

Is anyone else experiencing this? Is there a solution to it?

Comment: If you restart VLC does it never go out of sync or does it again go out of sync slowly? Also, is this happening with files that were fine with older versions of VLC, or with newer files that you never tested with older versions? I'm asking because it's possible your system is unable to handle newer HD files.

Comment: @Karan, It always goes out of sync slowly. The last file I tried was an mp4. I haven't tried the same file with an older version of vlc.

Comment: If you experience the same problem with older and newer versions of VLC, stands to reason it's not VLC but your system to blame.

Comment: I have the same problem with vlc, but I've noticed that it does it on online videos too (on Edge) so I'm wondering if it has something to do with video drivers.

Answer (score 5):

I have the same problem with VLC. The sync keeps on slipping regardless if it's a 480p crummy home video or a 4k quality feature film. If I play the same file with another media player, such as K-Lite or even WMP, then the problem does not exist at all.

A quick fix, that does alleviate the symptoms but does not cure the disease, is to use the keyboard shortcuts <kbd>J</kbd> and <kbd>K</kbd> to shift the audio up and down in increments of 50ms. This usually solves the problem temporarily.

Comment: Fixed the problem for me! +1

Answer (score 2):

i had the same problem where in iTunes where video stop but audio would continue then pause altogether then resume sum 20sec down the line but VLC would be fine as said above it boils down to system requirements and what would be used for that program. Be sure to look at  the requirements before you download.

Comment: seconded. I've seen this problem with XMBC too. Usually it's that your computer can't keep up with both streams, and the sync suffers.

Answer (score 2):

Try this - Go to Tools -> Preferences -> Click "show all" down the bottom left -> Input/Codecs. At the bottom in the advanced section the first option should be file caching. Try increase this to around 10,000 ms/ 10 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Just revert to version 2.1.5 Rincewind and it will be solved. I tried codek paks and everything was making it freeze and audio repeating and unsync. I used my old pc and it was flowing like a breeze

Comment: This seems anecdotal, might be best as a comment really. I appreciate that you may be unable to comment at this time.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me: `View` → `Renderer settings` → `Reset to default renderer settings` for MPC-BE.

It might have something to do with the renderer.